# Intellij Invokes AfterAllCallback Between Each Integration Test Class

Tags: intellij-idea, junit5, maven-failsafe-plugin

Context:

I'm using recent versions of relevant projects:

- Junit5 version `5.8.1`
- Intellij-Idea Ultimate `2021.2.3`
- maven-failsafe version `3.0.0-M5`

My project builds without error when running `mvn clean install` from my terminal. I use the maven-failsafe-plugin to execute my integration tests locally and in CI this way.

There are a lot of failsafe options to document, some of them inherited from parent poms, but failsafe is behaving as I expect.

The issue:

If I try to run all the integration tests from Intellij, Intellij seems to invoke `AfterAllCallback` extensions between each test class. This is different behavior than what I see from failsafe, which seems to be wrapping all tests in a single test container, only invoking the `AfterAllCallback` extensions once at the end. I very rarely run more than a single integration test class from the IDE, so I've never come across this before.

Questions:

- Is Intellij misbehaving or is there a failsafe setting I've set to do this?
- Can Intellij be configured to match the failsafe behavior?

Comment: You can use Maven to run tests in the IDE. See **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner > Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AfterAllCallback` is specified to run after all tests of each test class. In https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/AfterAllCallback.html it’s stated:

> provide additional behavior to test containers once after all tests in the container

If (and I haven’t checked) failsafe works differently it’s working against the specification.

Comment: Is a "test container" specified as a class? The terms seem ambiguous.

Comment: In the standard case the test container is the class and the individual methods are the tests. Concepts like parameterized and dynamic tests change that; there a single method can be a container as well. In your scenario that does not seem to be relevant, though.

Comment: Sounds like I need to upstream some patches to some test extensions that are misbehaving. Should this issue be brought to the attention of jupiter or failsafe?

Comment: I’d bet on Failsafe as the culprit. But that’s just a guess.